# html code change when get in json and save in string

Tags: android

I am getting HTML code from JSON save in string and load in webView problem is when save in string it will change so many  &lt &quot will shown any idea why? its not load image my screen look like this then https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaNqa.jpg what will i do/? how to decode it?? why is encode it? how to remove encoding? help

```
             WebView      wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);




          {"Status":1,
      "data":
  [
 {"product_id":"8569",




   "name":"Scalp Med Hair Grow PC-0004..",

 "description":"<p><b><font face="Arial">Scalp Med Hair Grow PC-0004.. <\/font><\/b><\/p>    
  \r\n\r  \n<p><img border="0" height="257"  src="http:\/\/www.megamall.com.pk\/image\/cache  
 \/data\/10011-Scalp-Med-Hairfall-Solution- 800x800.jpg" width="261" \/><\/p>\r\n\r 
 \n<p><b><font face="Arial" size="2">
 Features: <\/font><\/b><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p><font face="Arial" size="2"><b>Scalp Med Hair 
 Grow<\/b>    is an all natural formulation which includes the pure extracts of plants from 
 3 different continents.<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nIs your Bald Spot getting bigger and bigger 
 every   month?<br \/>\r\nIs the hair on your shower floor getting thicker while it gets
 thinner and thinner on your head?<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nThen Scalp Med Hair Grow
 is for you. Scalp Med Hair Grow is an all natural formulation which includes the
 pure extracts of plants from 3 different continents. This tried and tested formulation
 will reach deep down to cleanse, revitalize and unblock the hair follicles allowing vital   
 nutrients to reach the hair roots and allow hair to grow again.<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nScalp
  Med Hair Grow is the only ecological product of its kind capable of treating alopecia 
 efficiently. In the first month, continual use of Scalp Med Hair Grow will recover
 and strengthen the hair follicles. In the second month, your hair will stop 
 falling out altogether. And by the third month, new hair will start to grow.
  <\/font><\/p>\r\n",


 }

 ]}

  when get in json and save in string 


          String   htmldescription = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("description");

         wv.loadData(htmldescription, "text/html", "utf8");


     // String htmldescription  save data like this below


htmldescription ="

   &lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot;&gt;Scalp Med Hair Grow PC-0004..     
   &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;img border=&quot;0&quot; height=&     
   quot;257&quot; 
   src=&quot;http://www.megamall.com.pk/image/cache/data/10011-Scalp-Med-Hairfall-Solution-   
   800x800.jpg&quot; width=&quot;261&quot; /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot; size=&quot;2&quot;&gt;Features:  
  &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot; 
 size=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;Scalp Med Hair Grow&lt;/b&gt; 
 is an all natural formulation which includes the pure extracts of plants from 3 different    
 continents.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Is your Bald Spot getting bigger and bigger every
 month?&lt;br /&gt;Is the hair on your shower floor getting thicker while it gets thinner and   
 thinner on your head?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
 Then Scalp Med Hair Grow is for you. Scalp Med Hair Grow is an all natural 
 formulation which includes the pure extracts of plants from 3 different continents. This 
 tried  and tested formulation will reach deep down to cleanse, revitalize and unblock the hair 
follicles allowing vital nutrients to reach the hair roots and allow hair to grow again.&lt;br  
/&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
 Scalp Med Hair Grow is the only ecological product of its kind capable of
 treating alopecia efficiently. In the first month, continual use of Scalp Med Hair Grow will   
 recover and strengthen the hair follicles. In the second month, your hair will 
 stop falling out altogether. And by the third month, new hair will start to     
 grow.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try have a look at documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html