# how to save encoded html in string

Tags: android

How to save encoded value of html to string help me I'm saving html in string htmldescription but is encoded into show actual html see my this post [html code change when get in json and save in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656016/html-code-change-when-get-in-json-and-save-in-string)

Html code wil change when I save in textview with this command is show perfectly

`mytext= (Html.fromHtml(htmldescription));`

But I want to save in string what will i do? How to save encoded html(string) in string any idea???

```
String  htmldescription = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("description");
mytext= (Html.fromHtml(htmldescription));
String coverthtml= mytext?????????????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the original html value:

```
String  htmldescription = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("description");
```

And this is the html formatted value:

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(formattedText);
```

And this is the String conversion:

```
String formattedText = spanned.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Spanned first

```
Spanned mytext = Html.fromHtml(htmldescription);
```

now convert the spanned to string

```
String url=mytext.toString();
```

To know more details about spanned refer this url

[Android Spanned, SpannedString, Spannable, SpannableString and CharSequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546955/android-spanned-spannedstring-spannable-spannablestring-and-charsequence)