# How to Convert HTML to String android and print that string

Tags: android, html, url, printing, plaintext

I followed [this](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4601&scat=50&pcat=52)/[this](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4747&scat=61&pcat=52) to Print Receipts in part of POS(Point of Sale) from EPSON Printer

Here I am getting data Json from URL (inside the Json Object I am getting a html print template):

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": "<table>.... </table>"
    }
}
```

so with intent I used the above json response to a string and converted it to html:

```
method = "addFeedLine";
mPrinter.addFeedLine(1);

textData.append("Test print Sample string\n");**//this is sample text**

textData.append(Html.fromHtml(status + "\n"));
**//this is JSON response which is nothing but HTML code, so I am converting it to string**
```

Over there I have used `status` as a string so that whatever the content is inside that string, it is printed.

If it's is not a html but just a plain text I will print it like this

```
method = "addFeedLine";
mPrinter.addFeedLine(1);
textData.append(status);
```

Here is an example of what `status` looks like

```
"status": "The store list Sample\nSTORE DIRECTOR – XYZ\n01/01/01 16:58 6153 05 0191 134\nST# 21 OP# 001 TE# 01 TR# 747\n------------------------------\n400 OHEIDA 3PK SPRINGF 9.99 R\n410 3 CUP BLK TEAPOT 9.99 R\n445 EMERIL GRIDDLE/PAN 17.99 R\n438 CANDYMAKER ASSORT 4.99 R\n474 TRIPOD 8.99 R\n433 BLK LOGO PRNTED ZO 7.99 R\n458 AQUA MICROTERRY SC 6.99 R\n493 30 L BLK FF DRESS 16.99 R\n407 LEVITATING DESKTOP 7.99 R\n441 ** Blue Overprint P 2.99 R\n476 REPOSE 4 PCPM CHOC 5.49 R\n461 WESTGATE BLACK 25 59.99 R\n------------------------------\nSUBTOTAL 160.38\nTAX 14.43\nTOTAL 174.81\nCASH 200.00\nCHANGE 25.19\n------------------------------\nPurchased item total number\nSign Up and Save!\nWith Preferred Saving Card\n"
```

Now, here I have a plain HTML page:

```
Search Images Maps Play YouTube News Gmail Drive More »
Web History | Settings | Sign in

                  Louisa May Alcott’s 184th birthday

       [                                                         ] Advanced
                                                                   searchLanguage
                   [Google Search][I'm Feeling Lucky]              tools

 Advertising ProgrammesBusiness Solutions+GoogleAbout GoogleGoogle.com

                       © 2016 - Privacy - Terms
```

I need to print this from an url.

Can anyone suggest me how to print this plain text?
There is no HTML tags and no JSON data.

Comment: those mentioned links are not accessible.. so better to post the name and proper description of the sdk you are using rather than referring the links like you did.

Comment: I have Updated Link at bottom we have download link of sdk.....All the Persons Who downvoted Please upvote and All the Answers People Please Upvote I have already loosed in bounty

Answer (score 1):

By Html.fromHtml method you can convert HTML to String -

```
String strToHtml = Html.fromHtml(htmlContentInStringFormat)

Log.e(TAG,"strToHtml :: "+strToHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to print it like the html it really is, I recommend you to get the primary html code `status` (before parsing it and so on) and to push it into a WebView like this:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", status, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Otherwise, if you just want to print it into the screen, you can use a simple TextView to do that by `text_view.setText(textData.toString())`

Comment: Yes I want to Print Not view... Its theremal Print

Comment: Please, explain yourself better. First of all, what do you mean by "Print" (is it to print in the screen? or to send it for a printing service?). Second of all, what do you mean when you say "or How to add this plain text to a string", cause you already have the "status" String. Do you really need to send the String to a given printing service?

Comment: I dont Konw how do you print Thermal print screen ?????? I said Its thermal Print and I followed EPSON thermal Printer SDK Here there is no webview

Answer (score 0):

This is the original html value:

```
String  htmldescription = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("description");
```

This is the html formatted value:

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(formattedText);
```

And this is the String conversion:

```
String formattedText = spanned.toString();
```

Got it from here: [how to save encoded html in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657652/how-to-save-encoded-html-in-string)
If this doesn't work out you should check out the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Hope it Helps, Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `Regex` to convert `HTML template` to a `plain text`. It detects all types of HTML tags, but there may be loopholes.

For example:

```
// Regex pattern
private static final String STR_PATTERN = "\\<[^\\>]*\\>";

public static String htmlToPlainText(final String template) {

  // replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
  return (template.replaceAll(STR_PATTERN, ""));
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Actually Have URL I want to print the contents inside that url